# Strict regex in Pandas replace

Tags: regex, python-2.7, pandas, replace

I need to write a strict `regular expression` to replace certain values in my `pandas` dataframe. This is an issue that was raised after solving the question that I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46342492/use-dictionary-to-replace-a-string-within-a-string-in-pandas-columns/46342559#46342559).

The issue is that the `.replace(idsToReplace, regex=True)` is not strict. Therefore if the iDsToReplace are:

```
NY : New York
NYC : New York City
```

and the comment in which we are replacing the ID is:

```
My cat from NYC is large.
```

The resulting response is:

```
My cat from New York is large.
```

Is there a pythonic way within the `pandas` `replace` function to make the `regular expression` stricter to match with `NYC` and not `NY`?

Comment: there's no concept of strictness in regex, it just matches what you tell it to. You may be looking for `\b` word boundaries.

Comment: Sorry, do you need replace `My cat from NYC is large.` to `My cat from New York City is large.` if dict is `d = {'NYC': 'New York City', 'NY' : 'New York'}` ?

Comment: The issue was that the Word NYC was being captured by NY, instead of NYC. Thus the correct answer is: 'My cat from New York City is large'. I am doing some tests, but so far it seems as if your below answer is working with the `bounds`

Comment: @owwoow14 - Super, glad can help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `\b` for [`word boundaries`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995034/does-python-re-module-support-word-boundaries-b) to each key of `dict`:

```
d = {'UK': 'United Kingdom', 'LA': 'Los Angeles', 'NYC': 'New York City', 'NY' : 'New York'}

data = {'Categories': ['animal','plant','object'],
    'Type': ['tree','dog','rock'],
        'Comment': ['The NYC tree is very big', 'NY The cat from the UK is small',
                    'The rock was found in LA.']
}

d = {r'\b' + k + r'\b':v for k, v in d.items()}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['commentTest'] = df['Comment'].replace(d, regex=True)
print (df)
  Categories                          Comment  Type  \
0     animal         The NYC tree is very big  tree   
1      plant  NY The cat from the UK is small   dog   
2     object        The rock was found in LA.  rock   

                                         commentTest  
0                 The New York City tree is very big  
1  New York The cat from the United Kingdom is small  
2                 The rock was found in Los Angeles.
```