# string manipulation with python pandas and replacement function

Tags: python, string, pandas, replace, nltk

I'm trying to write a code that checks the sentences in a csv file and search for the words that are given from a second csv file and replace them,my code is as bellow it doesn't return any errors but it is not replacing any words for some reasons and printing  back the same sentences without and replacement.

```
import string
import pandas as pd
text=pd.read_csv("sentences.csv")
change=pd.read_csv("replace.csv")
for row in text:
    print(text.replace(change['word'],change['replacement']))
```

the sentences csv file looks like

[image]

and the change csv file looks like

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use dictionary to replace a string within a string in Pandas columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46342492/use-dictionary-to-replace-a-string-within-a-string-in-pandas-columns)

Comment: not that similar wasn't able to follow it sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
text=pd.read_csv("sentences.csv")
change=pd.read_csv("replace.csv")
toupdate = dict(zip(change.word, change.replacement))
text = text['sentences'].replace(toupdate, regex=True)
print(text)
```

Comment: thank you that worked fine can you explain the dict and zip function what they do in short for this code please

Comment: zip creates an iterable tuple with two lists and dict will create a dictionary out of the tuples as key, value pair

Answer (score 1):

`dataframe.replace(x,y)` changes complete x to y, not part of x.

you have to use regex or custom function to do what you want. for example :

```
change_dict = dict(zip(change.word,change.replacement))
def replace_word(txt):
    for key,val in change_dict.items():
        txt = txt.replace(key,val)
return txt
print(text['sentences'].apply(replace_word))
```

Comment: thank you I tried this as well but it should be in a for loop to do all sentences because it is just replacing the first sentence, can you enplane the first line of your code please the dict and zip what they do

Comment: .apply takes care of the loop, explained zip and dict on answer post

Comment: then your code is just doing it for the first replacement and stops

Answer (score 0):

// to create one more additonal column to avoid any change in original colum

```py
text["new_sentence"]=text["sentences"]

for changeInd in change.index:
    for eachTextid in text.index:
        text["new_sentence"][eachTextid]=text["new_sentence"][eachTextid].replace(change['word'][changeInd],change['replacement'][changeInd])
```

[clear code: click here plz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hqEe.png)